# O que fazer se o usuário final não quer colaborar?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software, gerenciamento-de-projetos, requisitos

Depois de ler bastante sobre metodologias ágeis e domain-driven design, fiquei convencido que é de vital importância para o desenvolvimento de um software que o especialista de domínio (que muitas vezes é o usuário final), participe do processo, converse com os desenvolvedores explicando o que o sistema precisa e como são as operações relacionadas naquele domínio.

O envolvimento do especialista de domínio permite então a construção de uma linguagem ubíqua, da qual é possível descobrir quais entidades, agregados e etc são necesários para construir o software. Conhecendo a linguagem ubíqua, as operações e os requisitos, se descobre também facilmente as responsabilidades de cada classe.

O problema é que isso supõe que antes de mais nada, o especialista de domínio queira colaborar ativamente com o desenvolvimento. O que eu tenho visto na prática, todavia, é justamente o oposto, o especialista de domínio não querer colaborar de jeito nenhum. Os principais pontos que tenho observado nesse aspecto são:

- O especialista de domínio evita reuniões presenciais e quer tratar tudo por e-mail ou outras vias textuais
- O especialista de domínio fornece os requisitos por via textual sem grandes explicações e não gosta de muito questionamento. Nesse ponto, para ele que está acostumado com aquele domínio, aquela explicação simples é suficiente e parece tudo óbvio. Para alguém de fora não é bem assim, e fica extremamente dificil entender o que ele quer afinal.
- O especialista de domínio acha que seu papel é *só dizer o que ele quer funcionando*. Ele acha totalmente desnecessário explicar o domínio com mais detalhes e não gosta que o desenvolvedor fique fazendo perguntas
- Já até teve um caso que ao responder um e-mail questionando alguns requisitos para ver se meu entendimento do requisito e do domínio estava correto, o especialista de domínio se irritou e falou que eu estava inventando coisas e complicando tudo, porque era tudo óbvio que ele tinha escrito.

Enfim, eu poderia elencar mais mil itens nesse sentido. Por tudo que li achei a proposta das metodologias ágeis e do domain-driven design *muito boas*. É uma proposta que responde várias perguntas difíceis como "como determinar o que deve ser programado", além de dar uma organização muito maior para o projeto. Acontece, todavia, que se isso é verdade, por outro lado, estou achando *muito difícil* fazer o especialista de domínio colaborar.

Minha pergunta aqui é: como fazer o especialista de domínio, o usuário final, de fato colaborar com o desenvolvimento para desenvolvermos a coisa certa?

Comment: Olá Leonardo, tudo bem? Então, isso é um assunto um tanto quanto amplo. Ao mesmo tempo que você acha que o profissional deverá ter contato com o cliente, várias empresas (especialmente fora do Brasil) pensam de forma distinta. Existe um profissional (ou mais) que tem a **responsabilidade** de levantar todos os requisitos da melhor forma possível. O que chega, até mesmo para o desenvolvedor, é apenas um documento com tudo "bonitinho". Cada empresa tem a sua metodologia. O tamanho, o tempo de casa, e algumas "normas" influenciam em como deve ser feito.

Comment: Comento isso com base em conversas que tenho com colegas de grandes empresas e outros que estão fora do Brasil à trabalho. Claro, não posso generalizar algo desse tipo, da mesma forma que acho que uma resposta para essa indagação não se encaixa no modelo do site. Claro, essa é a minha opinião e outros provavelmente pensam diferente.

Comment: Melhor do que só conversar com o usuário, é ficar olhando ele trabalhar. E de preferência, quem tem que fazer esse levantamento de requisitos precisa ter QI de 100 pra cima, pra avaliar do que o usuário faz e fala, quais partes estão corretas e quais precisam ser melhoradas. Já fiz e vi muitos levantamentos desse tipo em que mesmo antes de começar o desenvolvimento, a empresa já acabou corrigindo diversos procedimentos só com base no que foi constatado nessa fase. Mas aí depende do quanto você tem liberdade para interferir no processo, e o quanto a empresa que você representa é engessada.

Comment: Em termos práticos , alguém paga pelo projeto , seja em dinheiro ou pelas horas de trabalho da equipe interna , sendo você que está desenvolvendo não encontra apoio do usuário em qualquer fase (levantamento, teste , homologação etc) , deve primeiro tentar um contato com o mesmo ("ir na boa") , não funcionando levar o problema ao seu superior ou para quem paga pelo projeto (o "vai dar m****") e esperar que ou o cara faça sua função ou escalem alguém para isto.

Answer (score 4):

EU acredito que a melhor saída nessas situações são conversar com o patrocinador do projeto e demonstrar à ele quais são suas necessidades de informações e de atenção do usuário final, e ele se encarrega de solicitar isso à este usuário.

Se em último caso a situação continuar da forma mencionada (sem reuniões presenciais, e-mails sucintos, etc.) temos que fazer solicitações extremamente específicas de informações para que o assunto abordado seja aprofundado no ponto em que gostaríamos. Em muitos casos processuais, é interessante a realização de diagramas (ou algo do gênero) por parte do usuário para nosso melhor entendimento.

Infelizmente se fizermos algo sem a devida comunicação e auxílio do usuário que realmente entende do processo, é quase inevitável que haja retrabalho, e consequentemente mais horas dedicadas ao projeto.

Obs: Esta é a minha primeira tentativa de resposta e de certa forma estou "*Fazendo afirmações baseadas apenas na minha opinião*" (o que não é aconselhável como resposta). Mas realmente gostaria de expôr meu ponto de vista no assunto. Peço desculpas se estiver atrapalhando de alguma forma.